# Views have no rowid values

Tags: sqlite, sql-view

Views have no rowid, is that expected? Example:

```
create table t2 (u text);
insert into t2 values ('x');
insert into t2 values ('y');
create table t1 (t text, i integer);
insert into t1 values ('a',1);
insert into t1 values ('b',2);
insert into t1 values ('c',1);
insert into t1 values ('d',2);
create view v as select * from t1 join t2 on t1.i=t2.rowid;
select rowid,* from t1;
ro t  i
-- -- --
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  1
4  d  2
select rowid,* from v;
ro t  i  u
-- -- -- ----------
   a  1  x
   b  2  y
   c  1  x
   d  2  y
```

I worked around this by adding an 'ID' column to `t1` where ID=rowid. On the SQLite VIEW web page I found no reference to rowid.

I wanted to know if I misused the view. The view is to present a single table that links several related tables. I need to access the view by its 'rowid' because my tables are write-once (by a data extractor) then read-only. The data extractor knows what it entered and the rowid, then avoids to create a redundant column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowid` values identify table rows; views do not have rows stored in them.

To identify the rows from a table used in the view, you can simply include the `rowid` value from that table in the view:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT t1.rowid, ... FROM t1 ...;
```

---

Anyway, a column declared as [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) is an alias for the `rowid` (and therefore does not require extra storage).
If you actually want to use the `rowid` values, it would be a better idea to include such a column explicitly in the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    t TEXT,
    i INTEGER
);
```

(It still behaves as the `rowid`; you get [autoincremented values](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) by inserting NULL values into it.)

Comment: In nested queries (from non rowid tables) -`ROW_NUMBER()` can work w/o adding superfluous columns  with proper constraints.

Comment: @tkefauver What do you mean with "can work"? The return value of row_number() is not capable of identifying rows in the original table(s). This question is not about numbering rows.

Comment: @CL "can work" for selects not from a rowid tables? You guys need to chill out.